# How to remove an element in etree python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree

I want to remove an element from etree,how to do it? Here's the code

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse(open("Sample.xml",'r'))
for e in root.iter():
  if(some condition):
     root.remove(e)
```

the above code gives me 
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'remove'.
is there any other way to remove the element?

**result of dir(etree)**

> > > ['AncestorsIterator', 'AttributeBasedElementClassLookup', 'C14NError', 'CDATA', 'Comment', 'CommentBase', 'CustomElementClassLookup', 'DEBUG', 'DTD', 'DTDError', 'DTDParseError', 'DTDValidateError', 'DocInfo', 'DocumentInvalid', 'ETCompatXMLParser', 'ETXPath', 'Element', 'ElementBase', 'ElementChildIterator', 'ElementClassLookup', 'ElementDefaultClassLookup', 'ElementDepthFirstIterator', 'ElementNamespaceClassLookup', 'ElementTextIterator', 'ElementTree', 'Entity', 'EntityBase', 'Error', 'ErrorDomains', 'ErrorLevels', 'ErrorTypes', 'Extension', 'FallbackElementClassLookup', 'FunctionNamespace', 'HTML', 'HTMLParser', 'HTMLPullParser', 'LIBXML_COMPILED_VERSION', 'LIBXML_VERSION', 'LIBXSLT_COMPILED_VERSION', 'LIBXSLT_VERSION', 'LXML_VERSION', 'LxmlError', 'LxmlRegistryError', 'LxmlSyntaxError', 'NamespaceRegistryError', 'PI', 'PIBase', 'ParseError', 'ParserBasedElementClassLookup', 'ParserError', 'ProcessingInstruction', 'PyErrorLog', 'PythonElementClassLookup', 'QName', 'RelaxNG', 'RelaxNGError', 'RelaxNGErrorTypes', 'RelaxNGParseError', 'RelaxNGValidateError', 'Resolver', 'Schematron', 'SchematronError', 'SchematronParseError', 'SchematronValidateError', 'SerialisationError', 'SiblingsIterator', 'SubElement', 'TreeBuilder', 'XInclude', 'XIncludeError', 'XML', 'XMLDTDID', 'XMLID', 'XMLParser', 'XMLPullParser', 'XMLSchema', 'XMLSchemaError', 'XMLSchemaParseError', 'XMLSchemaValidateError', 'XMLSyntaxError', 'XMLTreeBuilder', 'XPath', 'XPathDocumentEvaluator', 'XPathElementEvaluator', 'XPathError', 'XPathEvalError', 'XPathEvaluator', 'XPathFunctionError', 'XPathResultError', 'XPathSyntaxError', 'XSLT', 'XSLTAccessControl', 'XSLTApplyError', 'XSLTError', 'XSLTExtension', 'XSLTExtensionError', 'XSLTParseError', 'XSLTSaveError', '_Attrib', '_BaseErrorLog', '_Comment', '_Document', '_DomainErrorLog', '_Element', '_ElementIterator', '_ElementMatchIterator', '_ElementStringResult', '_ElementTagMatcher', '_ElementTree', '_ElementUnicodeResult', '_Entity', '_ErrorLog', '_FeedParser', '_IDDict', '_ListErrorLog', '_LogEntry', '_ProcessingInstruction', '_RotatingErrorLog', '_SaxParserTarget', '_TargetParserResult', '_Validator', '_XPathEvaluatorBase', '_XSLTProcessingInstruction', '_XSLTResultTree', '**all**', '**builtins**', '**doc**', '**docformat**', '**file**', '**name**', '**package**', '**pyx_capi**', '**test**', '**version**', 'cleanup_namespaces', 'clear_error_log', 'dump', 'fromstring', 'fromstringlist', 'get_default_parser', 'htmlfile', 'iselement', 'iterparse', 'iterwalk', 'memory_debugger', 'parse', 'parseid', 'register_namespace', 'set_default_parser', 'set_element_class_lookup', 'strip_attributes', 'strip_elements', 'strip_tags', 'tostring', 'tostringlist', 'tounicode', 'use_global_python_log', 'xmlfile']

Comment: how do you import module? could you post result of `dir(root)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `e.getparent().remove(e)`?

Comment: Some information about how `ElementTree.iter` works and that `remove` can only be used on child elements may make this answer more complete, but I'm not sure it's necessary since this is a duplicate.